# xmpppy automatic reconnect

Tags: python, xmpppy

I want to run a little chatbot using xmpppy and a library called [pygtalkrobot](http://code.google.com/p/pygtalkrobot/) . However I have a pretty bad/old router so disconnects are frequent. I would like the script to somehow detect problems with the connection, either periodically every 5 minutes or something or using some event, and reconnect if there is a problem.

However I have no idea how to check that or what events to use (if any). The xmpppy API documentation is also pretty unclear in my opinion.